# Xamarin Forms - Adding constructor to MasterDetailPage.Master

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, master-pages

I have a Xamarin.Forms app with a master-detail page and it works well.

But I've recently needed to add a parameter to the constructor of the master page (AttendPageMaster), but now I need to pass this constructor.

How do I add a parameter to the xaml?

```
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <pages:AttendPageMaster x:Name="MasterPage" />
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
```

The code behind page with constructor:

```
public AttendPageMaster(AttendanceViewModel viewModel)
{
}
```

Let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: This error is not related to a constructor parameter. Just set the `Title` property:  <pages:AttendPageMaster x:Name="MasterPage" Title=" " />. Beside that, what is parameter type in the constructor?

Comment: Sorry i've not made it clear. I only get the title property problem when using the code behind approad. I'm looking at how i pass in a parameter (custom type) to the constructor using the xaml approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to pass `ViewModel` to `Page` via constructor, you can set the Page's `BindingContext`:

```
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <pages:AttendPageMaster x:Name="MasterPage">
        <pages:AttendPageMaster.BindingContext>
            <myViewModels:AttendanceViewModel />
        </pages:AttendPageMaster.BindingContext>
    </pages:AttendPageMaster>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
```

This solution will work if your `ViewModel` does not expect any parameters in constructor. Otherwise you may consider using `ViewModelLocator` and `DI` to inject the constructor parameters.
Please note that `myViewModels` should be defined in the header of your XAML page as `xmlns:myViewModels`.

P.S.: Previously you mentioned that you got an exception while trying to use code behind approach. You could easily solve it by setting the `Title` property of the `AttendPageMaster`. Example:

```
new AttendPageMaster(new AttendanceViewModel()){ Title = " " };
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this from the code behind by creating the menu page in the constructor of the masterdetail and assigning it to the "Master" property:

```
AttendMasterPageMaster MasterPage;

public AttendMasterPage(AttendanceViewModel viewModel)
    {
      MasterPage = new AttendMasterPageMaster(viewModel);
      Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(StartPage), viewModel));
      Master = MasterPage;
```